# how can i replace the string between the two indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a string suppose it is `india is great india` i want to replace india but only one . suppose is is last one with other character . I have done something which is not working perfectly. issue with this is that it is replacing first letter and secod time it will replace other .

actually i have a text area and i want to delete the whole word from specific position . here is the example [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxqemaLw/5/). If i remove any tag like `<companyname>`

my js code to delete on backspace is

```
if(e.keyCode==8)
             {
                 var strval=tb.value;
                  var dlted_tag = (strval).slice(thisMatchStart+1,thisMatchEnd);
                  tb.value=strval.replace(dlted_tag,"");
             }
```

I also tried this

```
if(e.keyCode==8)
             {
                 var strval=tb.value;
                  var dlted_tag = (strval).slice(thisMatchStart+1,thisMatchEnd);
                  tb.value=strval.replaceAt(thisMatchStart,"");
             }
```

replace at function is

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
```

nothing happening . No error

Comment: How do you know which accurance of the string to delete?

Comment: I have start and end point . thisMatchStart is the start point of tag .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 tb.value = strval.slice(0, thisMatchStart) + strval.slice(thisMatchEnd);
```

Comment: strval is not defined.

Comment: @ris it's defined in your code `var strval=tb.value;`